# spring dependency management gradle plugin dependency version jars

Tags: gradle, jar, version, dependency-management

Can import dependency management in two ways.

```
plugins {
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

dependencies {
   implementation platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.2.1")
}
```

I can go online in Maven Repository in see which versions are included for 'dependencies {implementation platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.2.1")}'.
How do I know which versions are included for any version of 'plugins{id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'}'?
Is there another location aside Maven Repository to verify the version jars for the dependency?

I searched online and found the versions in Maven Repository for 'dependencies'. Not sure where to find same information for gradle plugin.

Answer (score 0):

So the proper way to import the dependencies with the Gradle plugin is incomplete. The gradle script below is the proper way which allows to determine online from Maven Repository which dependency jar versions are included. Developer can use what ever version for plugin and dependencyManagement.

```
plugins {
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.2.1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just import it this way as well which can also use Maven Repository for 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.2.1' to determine which dependency jar versions are included.

```
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.1'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}
```